# How to toggle self/target element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Looking for some assistance for what is probably a super simple code, but I know nothing about JS. I pieced this together

```js
$(".menu li").click(function(){
 $(this).children().addClass('active')
 .parent().addClass('active').siblings().find('.active').removeClass('active')
 .parent().removeClass('active');
        
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/01sw52p9/
This is where I'm stuck at.

It toggles the active class on the selected category and the children when I switch to a new parent category, but it doesn't toggle closed when you click on the category while it's open..
I couldn't find a $(this).self or $(this).target  option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using `toggleClass()` for this?

```js
$('.menu-item').each(function(){
    let _this = $(this);
    if(_this.children('ul').length){
        _this.addClass('menu-item-with-children');
    }
    
});


$('.menu').on('click', '.menu-item-with-children > a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).next('ul').toggleClass('active');
    
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}


.submenu::after {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 16px;
  font-weight: 900;
  content: "+";
  color: #000;
  padding-left: 5px;
}



.sub-menu {
  display: none;
}

.active {display: block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul class="menu">

    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">

        <a tabindex="0">Submenu1</a>

            <ul class="sub-menu">

                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">One</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Two</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Three</a></li>
                
                <li class="menu-item">
                    
                    <a href="#">SubMenu2</a>
            
                    <ul class="sub-menu">

                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">One</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Two</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">SubMenu 3</a>
                            <ul class="sub-menu">
                                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">One</a></li>
                                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Two</a></li>
                                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Three</a></li>
                                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Four</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li class="menu-item">
                            <a href="#">Three</a>
                            <ul class="sub-menu">
                                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Design</a></li>
                                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Development</a></li>
                                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">SEO</a></li>
                                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Copywriting</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. I was stuck on this all weekend! You are fantastic. Thank you! This volunteer project is kicking my butt lol. =) Thank you Thank you Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Battaboombattabaam's answer was perfect, I just modified it to add closing the other links. Posting it here in case anyone else ever needs something like it.

````
$('.menu-item').each(function(){
    let _this = $(this);
    if(_this.children('ul').length){
        _this.addClass('menu-item-with-children');
    }
    
});
 
  
  $(".menu li").click(function(){
 $(this).children().addClass('active')
 .parent().addClass('active').siblings().find('.active').removeClass('active')
 .parent().removeClass('active');
    $('.menu').on('click', '.menu-item-with-children > a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).next('ul').toggleClass('active');
    
    
});
    
});```
````